# frown and mathop/stackrel/overset

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stacking-symbols

I need something like `\stackrel{\frown}{MM'}` to express the fact that `MM'` is some path. But I am not really satisfied by the look of the result. The `\frown` is too high. Would you please have a suggestion?

Edit 1: I just discovered that the font I'm using, ie kpfonts, offers a nice `widearc` command which suits my needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may try `\wideparen` from the yhmath package:

```
\usepackage{yhmath}
...
$\wideparen{MM'}$
```

In case you don't want to change the `largesymbol` font, it's possible to load only the `\wideparen` accent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{yhlargesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{\mathord}{yhlargesymbols}{"F3}

\begin{document}
$\wideparen{MM'}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`arcs`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/arcs/arcs.pdf) package for this. It provides the `\overarc` command. But this package seems to be broken on my computer. :(

You can also use `\wideparen` provided by [`yhmath`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/yhmath/yhmath.pdf) font package. `yhmath` is compatible with default CM fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}
$\wideparen{MM'}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

[`MnSymbol`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf) package, [`mathdesign`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mathdesign/mathdesign-doc.pdf) package, and maybe some other math font packages, also provide `\wideparen`. It would be great if you use MinionPro with MnSymbol, or Utopia with mathdesign fonts.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
$\wideparen{MM'}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In recent distributions, yhmath comes with a corresponding Type1 font.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, I didn't notice it. Then it's okey to use `yhmath`. BTW, `\adots` in `yhmath` is wrong for different font size, one should use `\iddots` from `mathdots` package instead. That's another reason I don't like `yhmath`.

Comment: Well, and `amatrix` env. in `yhmath` is not compatible with latest `amsmath`. Pity. It should be `\newenvironment{amatrix}{\left\langle\begin{matrix}}{\end{matrix}\right\rangle}`

Comment: I'd like to avoid another package.

Comment: @pluton: See revision 2. http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/15473/revisions

Answer (score 6):

Although this question is quite old, here’s a solution using TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\overbow}[1]{
   \tikz [baseline = (N.base), every node/.style={}] {
      \node [inner sep = 0pt] (N) {$#1$};
      \draw [line width = 0.4pt] plot [smooth, tension=1.3] coordinates {
         ($(N.north west) + (0.1ex,0)$)
         ($(N.north)      + (0,0.5ex)$)
         ($(N.north east) + (0,0)$)
      };
   }
}

\begin{document}
$ABC$ $\overline{ABC}$ $\overbow{ABC}$

$\overline{AB}$ $\overbow{AB}$

$\overline{MC}$ $\overbow{MC}$

$\overline{HA}$ $\overbow{HA}$

$\overline{AH}$ $\overbow{AH}$

$A \overline{A} \overbow{A}$

$xgfx \overline{gf}x \overbow{gf}x$
\end{document}
```

To use it with other fonts, the line width and shifting values may have to be adapted.

Answer (score 4):

In ConTeXt, this accent is provided by `\overparent`:

```
\starttext
$\overparent{MMM}$

\startformula
  \int_{\overparent{MM'}} f(x) dx
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Accent seems like a way to go (example with XITS and XeTeX, in Plain):

```
\def\frown{\XeTeXmathaccent"0"1"23DC}
$$ \frown{MM'} \int\limits_{\frown{MM'}} $$
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if in practice (I'm not mathematician, sorry) someone will need ever arcs wider than 4 or 5 lowercase characters. If this could be a real scenario, then  `\widearc` of `kpfonts`, or `\wideparen` of `yhmath` or `mathdesign`, or `\bigfrown`, probably are not the best solution, since like others extensible accents, are unable to expand too much:

[image: MWE]
[image: MWE]

This problem seem well solved with `\overparent` in Aditya answer, but this require ConTeX. For `pdflatex`, I think that a decent alternative could be `\overgroup` from  `mathabx` package:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\overgroup{M'}$
$\overgroup{MM'}$
$\overgroup{MMMM'}$
$\overgroup{MMMMMMMM'}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The context solution replies on the font, so it should also work with lualatex

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand\bigfrown[2][\textstyle]{\ensuremath{%
  \array[b]{c}\text{\scalebox{2}{$#1\frown$}}\\[-1.3ex]#1#2\endarray}}

\begin{document}

foo \bigfrown{MM'} bar

\[\int\limits_{\protect\bigfrown[\scriptstyle]{MM'}}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you but it does not work for an integral `\int_{\bigfrown{MM'}}`

Comment: @pluton: sure, as always `\int_{\protect\bigfrown{MM'}}`. However, the `\bigfrown`can also be defined as a protected definition.

Comment: correct but it does not scale down as it should

Comment: @pluton: true, could also be done by the command itself, but that need some more work. See edited example for a simple workaround when it is only needed once

Answer (score 2):

from fourier 
added in preamble

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMX}{}{}%%%
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}%%%
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widearc}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{216}
```

Use

```
\[\widearc{MM'} + \int\limits_{\widearc{MM'}}\]
```