# Use \overarc to represent an arc

Tags: arc

I  can not understand why the following tex file does not compile.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{arcs}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
$\overarc{POQ}$ $+ \widehat{QOR} + \widehat{ROP}= 2\pi r$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `arcs` seems to be broken. Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/frown-and-mathop-stackrel-overset if some of the answers can help you.

Comment: Also see [A better notation to denote arcs for an American high school textbook](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96680/5764) which uses a symbol from [`tipa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tipa) (`\texttoptiebar`).

Answer (score 1):

Discussed for other oversymbols here [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol/101136#101136).  Using scalerel, a variant of that solution is used here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
\begin{array}{c}
\stretchto{
  \scaleto{
    \scalerel*[\widthof{#1}]{\bigwedge}
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}} %WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
  }{1.25\textheight} % THIS STRETCHES THE WEDGE A LITTLE EXTRA WIDE
}{0.5ex}\\           % THIS SQUEEZES THE WEDGE TO 0.5ex HEIGHT
#1\\                   % THIS STACKS THE WEDGE ATOP THE ARGUMENT
\rule{0ex}{.01ex}
\end{array}
}

\newcommand\reallywideparen[1]{%
\begin{array}{c}
\stretchto{
  \scaleto{
    \scalerel*[\widthof{#1}]{\frown}
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}} %WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
  }{1.25\textheight} % THIS STRETCHES THE WEDGE A LITTLE EXTRA WIDE
}{0.5ex}\\           % THIS SQUEEZES THE WEDGE TO 0.5ex HEIGHT
#1\\                   % THIS STACKS THE WEDGE ATOP THE ARGUMENT
\rule{0ex}{.01ex}
\end{array}
}

\begin{document}
$\reallywideparen{POQ}$ $+ \reallywidehat{QOR} + \reallywidehat{ROP}= 2\pi r$
\end{document}
```

[image]