# Why am I getting a division by zero error?

Tags: rotating, dimensions

I was experimenting with the answer I got to an earlier questions of mine: [A better notation to denote arcs for an American high school textbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96681/22413)

I wrote a new command as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\arc[1]{%%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%%
  \ooalign{%%
    \raisebox{\ht9}{%%
      \resizebox{\wd9}{\dimexpr1.75\height}{%%
        \rotatebox{90}{)}}}\cr#1}}

\begin{document}

\arc{ABC}

\arc{A}

\arc{AB}

\end{document}
```

which works fine.  But, the problem comes up when I try defining things as follows:

```
\newcommand\arc[1]{%%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%%
  \ooalign{%%
    \raisebox{\ht9}{%%
      \resizebox{\wd9}{\dimexpr1.75\height}{%%
        \rotatebox{-90}{(}}}\cr#1}}
```

I've tried various ways of avoiding this (such as wrapping up the rotated material in its own box) all to no avail.

Why is this second approach not working?

Comment: `-89` works, but not `-90`.  Weird.  Even `-89.4` works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I do

```
\sbox0{\rotatebox{-90}{(}}\the\ht0
```

I see `0.0pt` and this should explain the problem. Why? Let's look what happens when I type

```
(\rotatebox{-90}{(}\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width 4pt
```

(the `\vrule` just shows where the baseline is):

[image]

Here's a picture of the bounding box of the parenthesis:

[image]

(again, the rule shows the baseline).

If I do

```
\newcommand\arc[1]{{%%
  \sbox\arcbox{#1}%%
  \ooalign{%%
    \raisebox{\ht\arcbox}{%%
      \resizebox{\wd\arcbox}{\dimexpr1.75\height}{%%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{(}}}\cr#1}}}
```

(notice the additional pair of braces, please) I get, from `\arc{ABC}`,

[image]

Note also that I declared `\newsavebox\arcbox`; better avoiding random usage of scratch registers.

***Always*** ensure that `\ooalign` is inside a group.

---

Explanation: when you do a rotation without specifying a center, the bottom left corner is used. So a box rotated -90 will *always* result in having height zero.

Comment: @A.Ellett I've just added the reason

Comment: Aah, you know, I just realized something else:  I keep forgetting that height isn't really what I naturally think of as the height.  Height is just that which is above the baseline....