# The convex arc and concave arc above letter

Tags: arc

I would like to have the convex arc and concave arc above letters as below.

[image]

The command `\texttoptiebar{d}` can produce the second "d". Is there any package that produces both arcs?

Comment: It is possible to use this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96680/a-better-notation-to-denote-arcs-for-an-american-high-school-textbook, using the symbol 62 of tipa but I not know the number of slot of the first arc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\smile}d(x\mid y)+\overset{\frown}d(x\mid y)+\overline d(x)$
\end{document}
```

in order to get:

[image]

Comment: It is the same of the image of the user. IMHO it is better to use \bar{} instead \overline{} because the bar is shifted much to the left. +1

Answer (score 3):

With `amssymb` and `accents`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

    \[ \accentset{\smallsmile}{d}(x\mid y)) + \accentset{\smallfrown}{d}(x\mid y)) + \bar{d}(x) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]