# Putting the symbol hat in math mode in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

How to put the hat in the above symbol in LaTeX?

Comment: Hat covers the whole expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Really wide hat symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol)

Comment: @Federico It is not a duplicate of the suggested question. OP wants hat after, not over the whole expression.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke that it is not what I understand from its comment above: "Hat covers the whole expression"

Comment: Sorry @Federico. I wanted to mean after the whole expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand, that it is like some kind of Fourier transform of the whole expression. An alternative version added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Sel}{\operatorname{Sel}}

\[
\Sel_{E}^{\Sigma_0}(\mathbb{Q}_\infty)_p{}\widehat{}
\]

But probably better

\[
(\Sel_{E}^{\Sigma_0}(\mathbb{Q}_\infty)_p)\,\widehat{}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If a really wide "hat" symbol that should cover the entire expression is what you're after, you may want to look into using the [Mathtime Professional 2 (mtpro2)](http://pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package. The full package isn't free of charge, but its "lite" subset, which is all that's needed to create a superwide hat symbol, is indeed free.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\Sel}{\operatorname{Sel}}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\widehat{\Sel_{\mathrm{E}}^{\Sigma_0}(\mathbb{Q}_\infty)_p}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

you write

> Hat covers the whole expression

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Sel}{\operatorname{Sel}}

\begin{equation*}
\widehat{\Sel_{E}^{\Sigma_0}(\mathbb{Q}_\infty)_p{}}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

also, you might want to check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol) question