# Vertical placing of wide accents in superscript

Tags: spacing, accents

The following code

```
$\widetilde{aaa} \quad L^{\widetilde{aaa}}$

$\tilde{aaa} \quad L^{\tilde{aaa}}$

$\widehat{aaa} \quad L^{\widehat{aaa}}$

$\hat{aaa} \quad L^{\hat{aaa}}$

$\overline{aaa} \quad L^{\overline{aaa}}$

$\bar{aaa} \quad L^{\bar{aaa}}$
```

produces the following output:

[image]

What is the reason for additional vertical spacing for `\widetidle` and `\widehat` in superscript and what can one do about it?

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default setting for math fonts in LaTeX (and Plain TeX) uses `cmex10` at all sizes (no scaling whatsoever).

This is because the `omxcmex.fd` file contains

```
\ProvidesFile{omxcmex.fd}
        [2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions]
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{cmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->sfixed*cmex10%
   }{}
\endinput
```

In Plain TeX the “equivalent” line is

```
\textfont3=\tenex \scriptfont3=\tenex \scriptscriptfont3=\tenex
```

You can remedy in LaTeX by loading `amsmath` that chooses the suitable (optically) scaled fonts at smaller sizes by means of

```
  \DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
    <-8>cmex7<8>cmex8<9>cmex9%
    <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmex10%
  }{}
```

This should probably be improved in modern settings where Type1 fonts for `cmex` are available by saying

```
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
  <-7.5>cmex7<7.5-8.5>cmex8<8.5-9.5>cmex9%
  <9.5->cmex10%
}{}
```

but this would be necessary only when nonstandard sizes are used.

Here's the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\widetilde{aaa} \quad L^{\widetilde{aaa}}$

$\tilde{aaa} \quad L^{\tilde{aaa}}$

$\widehat{aaa} \quad L^{\widehat{aaa}}$

$\hat{aaa} \quad L^{\hat{aaa}}$

$\overline{aaa} \quad L^{\overline{aaa}}$

$\bar{aaa} \quad L^{\bar{aaa}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're using Plain TeX, then add at the top of the file

```
\font\sevenex=cmex7
\font\fiveex=cmex7 at 5pt
\scriptfont3=\sevenex
\scriptscriptfont3=\fiveex
```

Complete example

```
\font\sevenex=cmex7
\font\fiveex=cmex7 at 5pt
\scriptfont3=\sevenex
\scriptscriptfont3=\fiveex

$\widetilde{aaa} \quad L^{\widetilde{aaa}}$

$\tilde{aaa} \quad L^{\tilde{aaa}}$

$\widehat{aaa} \quad L^{\widehat{aaa}}$

$\hat{aaa} \quad L^{\hat{aaa}}$

$\overline{aaa} \quad L^{\overline{aaa}}$

$\bar{aaa} \quad L^{\bar{aaa}}$

\bye
```

The output is the same as before.

### With `lmodern`

If using `lmodern`, one has to redeclare the `largesymbols` font, because `lmodern` loads the corresponding font at fixed size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$\widetilde{aaa} \quad L^{\widetilde{aaa}}$

$\tilde{aaa} \quad L^{\tilde{aaa}}$

$\widehat{aaa} \quad L^{\widehat{aaa}}$

$\hat{aaa} \quad L^{\hat{aaa}}$

$\overline{aaa} \quad L^{\overline{aaa}}$

$\bar{aaa} \quad L^{\bar{aaa}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: When using `lmodern`, the fixes that `amsmath` applies get "lost", and neither of your `DeclareFontShape` statements do work. How can I have them in the right place while using `lmodern`?

Comment: @Marian You have to redeclare also the `largesymbols` font. I'll add it.