# A mathbb version of widetilde

Tags: math-mode, fonts, accents

Essentially, I would like to be able to use a hollow version of `widetilde`, a bit like `$\mathbb P$` is a hollow version of a `$P$` with a very fat vertical line. It would really suit my purposes. I tried to be clever and stack two `widetilde`s to imitate the idea, but two issues happened : tilde is too short and the `widetilde`s don't align. So I think creating a new accent would be the better solution, but I don't know where to start.

[image]

Comment: Could you please include an image of the results you want to get?

Comment: @Skillmon : Done (it's not turned on the side on my phone... Bite me!) This represents what I would want $\fancywidetilde M$ to do.

Comment: I guess the route I'd take is something like the following: Create a macro which 1. measures the width of its argument, 2. draw a TikZ picture of your `\mathbb`-tilde which is stretched to that width above the argument.

Comment: @Skillmon : I know a fair bit about TikZ and LaTeX, it's the TeX part that I don't know how to do!

Comment: To measure the width of something: `\setbox0\hbox{<something>}` after that `\wd0`, `\ht0`, and `\dp0` contain the width, height, and depth, respectively. It does only work on stuff which can be used in a `\hbox` (which shouldn't be a problem for the stuff you want to put under a tilde). Then to print the character without using space: `\mathrlap{<something>}` (requires `\usepackage{mathtools}`). After that you put your TikZ-tilde with the width `\wd0` there. That's what I'd do (but I'm too lazy to do the `tikz` part of it, atm) :)

Comment: @Skillmon : Can you show me a MWE with a basic graphic that wouldn't require you to do impressive TikZ? Like a rectangle or circle or something. You could leave that part to me!  That would be super helpful! From your answer I feel that I could read your code but I can't put the pieces together. I'm missing the syntax...

Answer (score 7):

A "for fun" answer that only works in pdflatex, based on my answer here: [Outline text using TrueType fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125578/outline-text-using-truetype-fonts/313317#313317).  It could be cleaned up quite a bit.  It uses pdfliterals to get the glyph outline of `\widetilde`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath,stackengine}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\shadowfy[1]{\expandafter\shadowfypars#1\par\relax\relax}
\long\def\shadowfypars#1\par#2\relax{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \shadowfywords#1 \relax\relax%
  \fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\par\shadowfypars#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\shadowfywords#1 #2\relax{%
  \outline{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \shadowfywords#2\relax\fi%
}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}

\newcommand\widespecialtilde[1]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\shadowfy{$\widetilde{\mathcal{#1}}$}}{$\mathcal{#1}$}%
  {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
}
\begin{document}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.1}
$x = \widespecialtilde{M}$\medskip

\fillcolor{red!50}
\def\thickness{.05}
$y = \widespecialtilde{W}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! This looks perfect! I'll get back to you today. (I am only using pdflatex, so this might just do the trick!)

Comment: I tried to use it in my code, but it won't compile. I tried several fixes, but it's hard to go through code you never understood the syntax of (i.e. TeX). However, I tried a workaround and I realized that what I want over M is something similar to \scalebox{1.2}[0.7]{$\approx$} because in your case the hollow part of the tilde is too small and when one zooms out, it almost doesn't look hollow at all.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva That was my worry that, at small scale, the hollowed tilde would be indistinguishable.

Answer (score 5):

Using the tricks [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337989/121799), one may try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym,graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand{\Pffft}{\rotatebox{90}{\leftmoon}\kern-0.05em\rotatebox{90}{\rightmoon}}

%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337989/121799
\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
     \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
     \stackengine{-.1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
         \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\AC}{.5150\wd0}}{.6\ht0}%
     }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\newcommand{\reallywidehat}[1]{%
    \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
            \scaleto{%
                \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]                         
                {\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
                    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED     BIG WEDGE
            }{\textheight}% 
        }{0.5ex}}%
    \ensurestackMath{\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}}%
}

\newcommand{\DoubleTilde}[1]{%
    \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
            \scaleto{%
                \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]                         
                {\kern-.1pt\Pffft\kern-.1pt}%
                    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED     BIG WEDGE
            }{\textheight}% 
        }{1ex}}%
    \ensurestackMath{\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}}%
}

\begin{document}
~\DoubleTilde{A}~\DoubleTilde{AB}~\DoubleTilde{\text{koala bear}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Koalas aren’t bears, btw :-)

Comment: @WillRobertson Yes, that's why they like to hide under a fake tilde ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A basic setup (might not be the best approach though). As you suggested, I did not draw the tilde but only a bar. The problem with the `\hbox` approach is that the surrounding formatting switches are lost.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}

\newcommand*\fancytilde[1]{%
  \mathchoice
    {\fancytildehelper{\displaystyle}{#1}{0.3ex}}
    {\fancytildehelper{}{#1}{0.3ex}}
    {\fancytildehelper{\scriptstyle}{#1}{0.2ex}}
    {\fancytildehelper{\scriptscriptstyle}{#1}{0.15ex}}}

\newcommand*\fancytildehelper[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{$#1#2$}%
  \mathrlap{#2}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht0+#3\relax}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
      \draw (0,0) -- (\wd0,0);%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}

\begin{document}
$\fancytilde{foo}_{\fancytilde{bar}_{\fancytilde{baz}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow and give you my feedback! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility created by altering an `\approx` symbol with two vertical lines created with `\rule`.

[image]

First there is a macro `\bbtild` that overlays the `\approx` symbol in its original size with two lines using `\ooalign`. This creates the blackboardbold-like tilde symbol. The length `\aproxlen` is created in the preamble to be the width of the `\approx` symbol.

```
\newcommand{\bbtild}{%
    \ooalign{$\approx$\cr%
    \hfil$\rule[.8pt]{.27pt}{.55ex}\hspace{.787\aproxlen}\rule[2.1pt]{.27pt}{.55ex}$\hfil\cr}%
    }
```

Then there is the macro that expands the new `\bbtild` symbol to the `\widthof` the desired character or characters:

```
\newcommand{\fancytilde}[1]{%
    \setlength{\fancylen}{\widthof{${#1}$}}%
    \overset{\resizebox{\fancylen}{.6ex}{$\bbtild$}}{#1}%
    }
```

Adjusting the `.6ex` will change the thickness of the new symbol. The complete code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for \resizebox
\usepackage{calc} % needed for \widthof 

\newlength{\fancylen}
\newlength{\aproxlen}

\setlength{\aproxlen}{\widthof{$\approx$}}

\newcommand{\bbtild}{%
    \ooalign{$\approx$\cr%
    \hfil$\rule[.8pt]{.27pt}{.55ex}\hspace{.787\aproxlen}\rule[2.1pt]{.27pt}{.55ex}$\hfil\cr}%
    }

\newcommand{\fancytilde}[1]{%
    \setlength{\fancylen}{\widthof{${#1}$}}%
    \overset{\resizebox{\fancylen}{.6ex}{$\bbtild$}}{#1}%
    }

\begin{document}

$\fancytilde{N}\fancytilde{M}\fancytilde{\mathcal{M}}\fancytilde{AB}$

\end{document}
```

Note that the vertical lines start to get very thick if the `\fancytilde` has to cover many characters. Note also that if you want to use this as a subscript you will have to use the form

```
$T_{\fancytilde{\scriptstyle N}}$
```

since the style of the input is not carried into the macro. If you wish, this could be done using `\mathchoice`.

Comment: Looks very good! Originally tried something very similar, but in my attempts the vertical `\rule`s got very ugly when I stretched the tilde too much.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I have the following temporary solution for myself which is slightly satisfactory :

```
\newcommand{\fancytilde}[1]{\overset{\mbox{}\scalebox{1.2}[0.7]{$\approx$}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Fancytilde}[1]{\overset{\mbox{}\scalebox{2}[0.7]{$\approx$}}{#1}}
```

I get my tilde M via

```
$\fancytilde M$
```

in the document.

However, whenever there's TeX involved, I don't know how to tweak it. I didn't manage to compile the above answers. It would be nice if my command would stretch to its argument (hence my need for two commands, one for a single letter and one for potentially more symbols).

I inspired myself from the above answers, so I'd like to thank everyone!