# Undefined control sequence. <argument> \SavedStyle \mkern .2mu\AC

Tags: stackengine, scalerel

I am attempting to adapt the code for `\reallywidehat` from a 2016 post, [What does \stackMath do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337988/what-does-stackmath-do), into my fairly large project as I transition typesetting from LaTeX to LuaLaTeX.

Typesetting the following MWE with LuaLaTeX:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor} 
\documentclass[12pt]{book}  

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}    

\begin{document}

% From: What does \stackMath do?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337988/what-does-stackmath-do
\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
     \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
     \stackengine{-.1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
        \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\AC}{.5150\wd0}}{.6\ht0}%
     }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
 }}

\reallywidetilde{Hypothesis}

\end{document}
```

Results in the following error:

```
reallywidetilde.tex:18: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \SavedStyle \mkern .2mu\AC
```

Note: The MWE in the post at [What does \stackMath do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337988/what-does-stackmath-do) runs w/o error, and creates a PDF file with the following image:

[image]

for the following code:

```
\reallywidetilde{A}
\test{abcdefghijklm}
\test{abcdefghijk}
\reallywidehat{abcde}
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \SavedStyle \mkern .2mu\AC` error in the above MWE *emphasized text*would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for reading.

Comment: the code you reference has `\usepackage{wasysym}` to define `\AC`

Comment: @David Carlisle - Thank you ... Yes, of course, silly me if I overlooked that ... Let me have a look to see if my larger project is missing `\usepackage{wasysym}` ... could be a simple fix! If so, I'll let you know tomorrow ... Then, if you'd like, and can post an `answer`, I can give you credit. Thanks again! P.S. ... That was FAST!

Comment: @David Carlisle - OK ... I just checked, and that worked!! Thank you ... if you don't mind posting your comment as an answer, I can give accept it to give you credit. Apologies for making such a silly error ... Thank you for all your help! Now I'm onto the next LaTeX -> LuaLaTeX typesetting conversion issue!

Comment: @David Carlisle - Thank you! (I should have caught this one myself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you reference has `\usepackage{wasysym}` to define `\AC`