# Latex - How to type these symbols over chars in matrix

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to to ask how I can type this matrix, especially that ^ over alphabetic characters.

[image]

I have something like this:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a+b & \overset{}{\epsilon + \omega} &  \overset{}{\pi} \\
        \vec{a} & \overleftrightarrow{AC} & \beta
    \end{pmatrix}
 \end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `\hat{a}`?

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray` -- it's badly deprecated. For the equation in your example, just use an `equation` environment.

Comment: For hat symbols over lowercase letters, use `\hat`. For hat symbols over uppercase Latin and Greek letters, use `\widehat`. For *really wide* hat symbols, see the posting [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100574/5001).

Comment: Yes, its `\widehat` and `\hat`. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, in ConTeXt with `\widehat` always expands to the width of it's argument. So, simply using `\widehat{ξ + ω}` works.

```
\definemathmatrix[pmatrix][matrix:parentheses][simplecommand=pmatrix]
\starttext
\startformula
  \pmatrix{ a + b, \widehat{ξ + ω}, \hat π;
           \vec a, \overleftrightarrow{AC}, β}
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to produce the really-wide hat symbol is to employ the `mtpro2` package. Note that the full [mtpro2 package](https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html) is not free of charge. However, its `lite` subset -- which is all that's needed to produce the screenshot of interest, is in fact free of charge.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' env.
\usepackage{times}        % Times Roman text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a+b     & \widehat{\xi + \omega}  & \hat{\pi} \\
    \vec{a} & \overleftrightarrow{AC} & \beta
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the default fonts, you have two possibilities for the widehat: either the extensible character `\widehat` from `yhmath`  or the character of the same name in `mathabx`. I don't load here mathabx, but define the latter character as `\varwidehat`. I also suggest the `old-arrows` package so that `\overleftrightarrow` doesn't touch capital letters:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{old-arrows}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\varwidebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}
\DeclareMathAccent{\varwidehat}{0}{mathx}{"70}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{pmatrix}
    a+b & \widehat{\xi + \omega} & \overset{}{\pi} \\
    \vec{a} & \overleftrightarrow{AC} & \beta
\end{pmatrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}
    a+b & \varwidehat{\xi + \omega} & \overset{}{\pi} \\
    \vec{a} & \overleftrightarrow{AC} & \beta
\end{pmatrix}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]