# \hat not extending over name of variable

Tags: equations

I'm using \hat in my regression equation, but it doesn't look too good the way it is. Any tips?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}

\hat{CEO Salary}

\end{document}
```

Any tips? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Replace it with `\widehat`. I do not know where you want to insert \hat. On the whole word or on the letter S? Here there is an excellent answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol.

Comment: `\hat` is supposed to be for one letter only. Try `\widehat` as Sebastiano said. But it will stretch up to 3 letter or so at max. For more than that see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101136/134574

Comment: My tip: Don't use `CEO Salary` as a variable, but some single symbol/letter, perhaps with an index, and tell the people that, e.g. `$\xi$ is the CEO's salary.`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank for my positive comment. Slowly thanks to all of you I'm quicker to give the right answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to employ Times Roman text and math fonts, the [mtpro2 package](https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html) may be of interest to you as it provides an extra-wide version of `\widehat`. Note that the full `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge. However, the package's `lite` subset, which is all that's needed for `\widehat`, may be downloaded free of charge.

[image]

Note that I encased the variable name, "CEO Salary", in a `\textrm` "wrapper".

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}    % Times Roman text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\begin{document}
$\widehat{\textrm{CEO Salary}}=\hat{\beta}_0 +\hat{\beta}_1 X_i$
\end{document}
```