# Using scalerel and stackengine packages changes table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, packages

I am using `\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}`. When I added `scalerel` and `stackengine` packages in order to solve the `\widehat` problem (as described in the [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101136/149630)) appearance of table of contents changed. Is there a way of using these packages without changing the table of content?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
\scaleto{%
\scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
{\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
}{\textheight}%
}{0.5ex}}%
\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}
\parskip 1ex

\title{ToC}
\author{ABCD}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
```

More precisely, when I remove the part starting from `\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}` and ending before `\title{ToC}` appearance of table of contents changes.

Comment: Could you please add a complete but minimal example of code showing the issue?