# Angle bracket over terms. "Vertical angle bracket"?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I am attempting to reproduce an existing typeset equation. I am unable to find an `\overanglebracket` command.

Two instances illustrate what I hope to accomplish.

Comment by @SebGlav leads me to `\wedge` and the `stackengine` and `scalerel` packages.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}

\[\widehat{AOB}\]

\[\stackon[2pt]{AOB}{\hstretch{3.75}{\wedge}}=θ-\frac{π}{2};\]

\[\stackon[2pt]{KCA}{\hstretch{3.75}{\wedge}}=2\stackon[2pt]{KOA}{\hstretch{3.75}{\wedge}}=2θ.\]
\end{document}
```

and I obtain:

[image]

[image] and [image]

Comment: `\widehat{AOB}` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @SebGlav Your comment led me to [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol)