# How to make wide grave and acute accents accurate also in \smaller when using TeX Gyre Termes Math and lualatex?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, accents, math-fonts, tex-gyre-math

Continuing [Wide acute and wide grave for TeX Gyre Termes and TeX Gyre Termes Math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611151) , we try to make wide grave and accute accents work in `\smaller` with TeX Gyre Termes (Math) fonts and UTF-8 engines (for NewTX and `pdflatex`, cf. [How to make wide grave and acute accents accurate also in \smaller when using NewTX and pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643181) ):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]%%% Somewhat ok.
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}%%% No explicit turning on ligatures for the monospaced font.
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}\stackMath
\usepackage{relsize}
%%% thanks to  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611030
\newcommand\wideacute[1]{%
  \ThisStyle{\savestack\tmpA{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \savestack{\tmpbox}{$\SavedStyle\stretchto{%
    \scalerel*[\wd\tmpAcontent]%
      {\kern-.83\LMpt\Umathchar"7"0"00B4\kern-.12\LMpt}%
    {\rule{0ex}{\textheight}}%
  }{2\LMex}$}%
  \stackengine{-6.3\LMpt}{\SavedStyle#1}{\tmpbox}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}%
}
\newcommand\widegrave[1]{%
  \ThisStyle{\savestack\tmpA{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \savestack{\tmpbox}{$\SavedStyle\stretchto{%
    \scalerel*[\wd\tmpAcontent]%
      {\kern-.43\LMpt\char"0060%
        \kern-.9\LMpt}%
    {\rule{0ex}{\textheight}}%
  }{1.05\LMex}$}%
  \stackengine{-2.3\LMpt}{\SavedStyle#1}{\tmpbox}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}%
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\(\displaystyle \wideacute{#1}\ \widegrave{#1}\) \(\textstyle \wideacute{#1}\ \widegrave{#1}\) \(\scriptstyle \wideacute{#1}\ \widegrave{#1}\) \(\scriptscriptstyle \wideacute{{#1}}\ \widegrave{#1}\)}%
\newcommand{\ttest}[1]{\test{#1}\\{\smaller\test{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\tttest}[1]{\ttest{\mathit{#1}}}%
\noindent
\tttest{sum}\\
\tttest{loop}\\
\tttest{pool}\\
\tttest{buffer}\\
\ttest{\sigma_k}
\end{document}
```

Feeding this to `lualatex` results in

[image: output]

As you see, the distance between a word and its accent is somewhat acceptable in normal-size font (though you could also complain there that this distance is too large in the grave'd “loop” and the acute'd “pool”).
However, in the version in `\smaller` these two parts overlap, which is undesirable. How to introduce a dependency on the font size so that the normal-size version still looks good (or, at least, not worse than it currently is, i.e., the accent should still sit just above the word) and the smaller-size version looks better (i.e., the accent should not overlap the word)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
\stackengine{-1.3\LMex}{\SavedStyle#1}{\tmpbox}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}%
```

in the definition of `\wideacute` and

```
\stackengine{-.4\LMex}{\SavedStyle#1}{\tmpbox}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}%
```

in the definition of `\widegrave`.

Comment: Thanks! Is the main insight changing the units from `\LMpt` to `\LMex`? Unfortunately, the distance between the accented text and the accent got larger also in normal font: http://i.imgur.com/p5ipSse.png .

Comment: I ended up with `\stackengine{-1.38\LMex}{\SavedStyle#1}{\tmpbox}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}%` in `\wideacute` and `\stackengine{-.52\LMex}{\SavedStyle#1}{\tmpbox}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}%` in `\widegrave`: http://imgur.com/g2K03Ko.png .