# yhmath impact on radical symbols and delimiters

Tags: delimiters, sqrt, root, yhmath, radicals

In November 2014 I had an issue with this code and `yhmath` package:

```
\sqrt{n+\sqrt{(n-1)+\sqrt{(n-2)+\dotsb+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1}}}}}
```

Depending on whether that package was being used or not (and AMS-packages used in both cases), the radical symbols were rendered differently (as described in Section 6: New roots of `yhmath` docs).

Edit (MWE): If I am not mistaken, radical symbols were rendered differently depending on whether `yhmath` was being used or not (the reason for using it was the `\wideparen` command).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
  \[ \sqrt{n+\sqrt{(n-1)+\sqrt{(n-2)+\dotsb+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1}}}}}<\sqrt{n}+1. \]
  \[ \wideparen{AB} \]
\end{document}
```

The package was also corrupted in MiKTeX back then (https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2201/) but eventually fixed.

Nowadays, the radical symbols are not rendered differently in two described cases, so I am wondering whether the explanation in Section 6 is still valid or not.

Can someone investigate does `yhmath` nowadays really change "large symbols"? How about "big delimiters" (also mentioned in `yhmath` docs)?

Thanks. Kind regards, Ivan

**Edit 2.**
It seems there are no differences on my machine: MiKTeX on Windows, `yhmath` packaged on Feb 2, 2018, v1.3. Excerpt from the log:

```
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/yhmath\yhmath.st
y"
Package: yhmath 
\symyhlargesymbols=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 14.
)
```

But the differences are present on other machine: MiKTeX on Windows, `yhmath` packaged on Jul 9, 2013, v1.1. Excerpt from the log:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\yhmath\yhmath.sty"
Package: yhmath 
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/lmex/m/n --> OMX/yhex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/lmex/m/n --> OMX/yhex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 14.
)
```

[image: v1.3 vs v1.1]

So, the question is: **Should `yhmath` affect big delimiters and big radical symbols?** I guess this remark in `yhmath` docs

> 2.2 Version v1.2 Yannis found that the current version conflicts with MTpro fonts due to concurrent use of the term largesymbols. This
>   version only changes this to yhlargesymbols.

should tell something about it, but I do not understand it.

If it should, then the latest version should be fixed. In this case, would something like this ([frown and mathop/stackrel/overset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/frown-and-mathop-stackrel-overset/15470#15470)) be possible to "extract" only the `\wideparen`?

Otherwise, Sections 4 and 6 (at least) in the docs are not valid anymore.

Kind regards, Ivan

Edit 3. Maybe norbert (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10829/norbert) can tell more as he maintains the package on CTAN?

Comment: Please show a complete example, not only some snippets. That makes it much easier to test.

Comment: MWE and other detailed information are added to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.4 which has been uploaded to CTAN and is already included in TeX Live fixes this issue by reverting to the old behavior, and allowing to switch to the 1.2/1.3 behavior with the package option `minimal`. Furthermore one can now disable the definition of the `widering` macro to support collaboration with other packages.

Comment: Great work! Please check the following issue with < and >: https://github.com/TeX-Live/yhmath/issues/1.

Comment: Fixed in version 1.5, which should be in TL tomorrow