Externalize on Overleaf
I am using a template given by my uni and running it on ShareLatex/Overleaf. I am currently running into an issue when trying to plot more data using tikz, that gives the follwoing error:
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].

After doing some research it seems to me the best solution to this is to use \externalize. I have tried to use \externalize on the project before and it did not work, so I just continued wthout it. Now, I think I need it to be able to continue. The project is really large with many folders, etc, so I have made an MWE. It has this as a main:
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}

% TODO: decide if one-sided/two-sided
%\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=12mm,DIV=12]{scrbook} % two-sided % original source stated: BCOR=12mm,DIV=12
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12]{scrbook} % one-sided

% TODO: change citation style in settings
\input{settings}

% TODO: change thesis information
\newcommand*{\getUniversity}{Technische Universität München}
\newcommand*{\getFaculty}{Department of Informatics}
\newcommand*{\getTitle}{Thesis title}
\newcommand*{\getTitleGer}{Titel der Abschlussarbeit}
\newcommand*{\getAuthor}{Author}
\newcommand*{\getDoctype}{Thesis type (Bachelor's Thesis in Informatics, Master's Thesis in Informatics: Games Engineering, \ldots)}
\newcommand*{\getSupervisor}{Supervisor}
\newcommand*{\getAdvisor}{Advisor}
\newcommand*{\getSubmissionDate}{Submission date}
\newcommand*{\getSubmissionLocation}{Munich}

\begin{document}

% TODO: decide on used language
%\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\selectlanguage{english}

% Set page numbering to avoid "destination with the same identifier has been already used" warning for cover page.
% (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Problems_with_Links_and_Pages).
\pagenumbering{alph}
\input{pages/cover}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzpics/]

\frontmatter{}

\input{pages/title}
\input{pages/disclaimer}
\input{pages/acknowledgements} % TODO: if you don't have anyone to thank for or don't wish to publish it, comment this line out.
\input{pages/abstract}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\tableofcontents{}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

\mainmatter{}

% \input{chapters/00_template}
\input{chapters/02_theory}


\appendix{}

% TODO: appendix chapter
\input{pages/appendix}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
% \listoffigures{}
% \listoftables{}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
% trying to print glossary
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist]
\printglossary
%
\printbibliography{}

\end{document}

In the settings.tex, all the packages are defined:
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % english is the same as american or USenglish
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  url=true,
  style=numeric, % alphabetic, numeric
  sorting=none, % default == nty, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order
  maxnames=4,
  minnames=3,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits,
  uniquename=init]{biblatex} % TODO: adapt citation style
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrhack} % necessary for listings package
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for better looking table creations, but bad with vertical lines by design (package creator despises vertical lines)
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % hidelinks removes colored boxes around references and links
\usepackage{ifthen} % for comparison of the current language and changing of the thesis layout
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % string compare to work with all engines
\usepackage{paralist} % for condensed enumerations or lists
% \usepackage{subfig} % for having figures side by side
\usepackage{siunitx} % for physical accurate units and other numerical presentations
\usepackage{multirow} % makes it possible to have bigger cells over multiple rows in a table
\usepackage{array} % different options for table cell orientation
\usepackage{makecell} % allows nice manual configuration of cells with linebreaks in \thead and \makecell with alignments
\usepackage{pdfpages} % for including multiple pages of pdfs
\usepackage{adjustbox} % can center content wider than the \textwidth
\usepackage{tablefootnote} % for footnotes in tables as \tablefootnote
\usepackage{threeparttable} % another way to add footnotes as \tablenotes with \item [x] <your footnote> after setting \tnote{x} 


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42619/x-mark-to-match-checkmark
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

%%%%% Packages Matis has addded
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %for plots
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta,external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
% \tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzpics/, figure name=output]
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,intersections,shapes.geometric,positioning}

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}
\usepackage{subcaption} % For subfigures

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{physics}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI} % as physics and siunitx packages both have a \qty command
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{trfsigns} % transformation signs for Fourier and Laplace
\usepackage{circuitikz} % for circuits
\usepackage{yhmath} % for \wideparen command; if causes issues: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/frown-and-mathop-stackrel-overset

%%%%%

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} % TODO: include "acronym" if glossary and acronym should be separated

% \loadglsentries{pages/glossary.tex} % important update for glossaries, before document
\input{pages/glossary}
\makeglossaries

\bibliography{bibliography}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries} % use serif font for headings
\linespread{1.05} % adjust line spread for mathpazo font

% Add table of contents to PDF bookmarks
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}}}

% Define TUM corporate design colors
% Taken from http://portal.mytum.de/corporatedesign/index_print/vorlagen/index_farben
\definecolor{TUMBlue}{HTML}{0065BD}
\definecolor{TUMSecondaryBlue}{HTML}{005293}
\definecolor{TUMSecondaryBlue2}{HTML}{003359}
\definecolor{TUMBlack}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{TUMWhite}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{TUMDarkGray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{TUMGray}{HTML}{808080}
\definecolor{TUMLightGray}{HTML}{CCCCC6}
\definecolor{TUMAccentGray}{HTML}{DAD7CB}
\definecolor{TUMAccentOrange}{HTML}{E37222}
\definecolor{TUMAccentGreen}{HTML}{A2AD00}
\definecolor{TUMAccentLightBlue}{HTML}{98C6EA}
\definecolor{TUMAccentBlue}{HTML}{64A0C8}

\definecolor{electriccyan}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{mediumgrey}{rgb}{0.57, 0.64, 0.69} % medium grey (cadetgrey)
\definecolor{royalpurple}{rgb}{0.47, 0.32, 0.66}
\definecolor{photoresist}{RGB}{255,99,71}
\definecolor{substrate}{RGB}{176,196,222}
\definecolor{yig}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0} % Amber 
\definecolor{silver}{rgb}{0.79, 0.75, 0.73} % Pale Silver

\pgfdeclarepattern{
  name=hatch,
  parameters={\hatchsize,\hatchangle,\hatchlinewidth},
  bottom left={\pgfpoint{-.1pt}{-.1pt}},
  top right={\pgfpoint{\hatchsize+.1pt}{\hatchsize+.1pt}},
  tile size={\pgfpoint{\hatchsize}{\hatchsize}},
  tile transformation={\pgftransformrotate{\hatchangle}},
  code={
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.1pt}{-.1pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\hatchsize+.1pt}{\hatchsize+.1pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.1pt}{\hatchsize+.1pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\hatchsize+.1pt}{-.1pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
}

\tikzset{
  hatch size/.store in=\hatchsize,
  hatch angle/.store in=\hatchangle,
  hatch line width/.store in=\hatchlinewidth,
  hatch size=5pt,
  hatch angle=0pt,
  hatch line width=.5pt,
}


% Settings for pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
  % For available color names, see http://www.latextemplates.com/svgnames-colors
  cycle list={TUMBlue\\TUMAccentOrange\\TUMAccentGreen\\TUMSecondaryBlue2\\TUMDarkGray\\},
}

% Settings for lstlistings

% Use this for basic highlighting
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  autogobble,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{TUMBlue},
  stringstyle=\color{TUMAccentGreen}
}

% use this for C# highlighting
% %\setmonofont{Consolas} %to be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
% \definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0,0,1}
% \definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
% \definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.64,0.08,0.08}
% \definecolor{xmlcomments}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
% \definecolor{types}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.68}

% \lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
% captionpos=b,
% %numbers=left, % numbering
% %numberstyle=\tiny, % small row numbers
% frame=lines, % above and underneath of listings is a line
% showspaces=false,
% showtabs=false,
% breaklines=true,
% showstringspaces=false,
% breakatwhitespace=true,
% escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
% commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
% morekeywords={partial, var, value, get, set},
% keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
% stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
% basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
% }

% Settings for search order of pictures
\graphicspath{
    {logos/}
    {figures/}
}

% Set up hyphenation rules for the language package when mistakes happen
\babelhyphenation[english]{
an-oth-er
ex-am-ple
}

% Decide between
%\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{\textcolor{TUMAccentOrange}{(TODO: #1)}}}} % for one paragraph, otherwise error!
%\newcommand{\done}[1]{\textit{\textsc{\textcolor{TUMAccentBlue}{(Done: #1)}}}} % for one paragraph, otherwise error!
% and
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\bfseries{\scshape{\color{TUMAccentOrange}[(TODO: #1)]}}}} % for multiple paragraphs
\newcommand{\done}[1]{{\itshape{\scshape{\color{TUMAccentBlue}[(Done: #1)]}}}} % for multiple paragraphs
% for error handling of intended behavior in your latex documents.

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % for horizontal alignment with limited column width
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % for horizontal and vertical alignment with limited column width
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % for vertical alignment left with limited column width
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % for vertical alignment right with limited column width

In 02_theory.tex, I just input the figure that I would like to externalize as an example:
\chapter{Theoretical Background}\label{chapt:theoretical_background}

\input{figures/CPW}

The figure CPW.tex is like this:
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % \fill[yig] (0,0) rectangle (5.25,7);
        \fill[silver] (0.75,0) rectangle (1.5,6);
        \fill[silver] (2.25,0) rectangle (3,6);
        \fill[silver] (3.75,0) rectangle (4.5,6);
        \fill[silver] (0.75,5.25) rectangle (4.5,6);
        % Labels
        \draw [>=Triangle, <->] (0.75,4.5) -- (1.5,4.5) node [midway, below] {$W_g$};
        \draw [>=Triangle, <->] (3.75,4.5) -- (4.5,4.5) node [midway, below] {$W_g$};
        \draw [>=Triangle, <->] (2.25,4.5) -- (3,4.5) node [midway, below] {$W_\mathrm{trans}$};
        \draw [>=Triangle, <->] (1.5,3.5) -- (2.25,3.5) node [midway, below] {$G$};
        \draw [>=Triangle, <->] (3,3.5) -- (3.75,3.5) node [midway, below] {$G$};
        \draw [>=Triangle, <->] (0,0) -- (0,5.25) node [midway, left] {$l$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}\label{fig:TopViewCPW}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill [substrate] (-2,0) rectangle (6,1);
        \fill [yig] (-2,1) rectangle (6,1.3);
        \fill [silver] (-1.1,1.3) rectangle (0.3,2);
        \fill [silver] (1.3,1.3) rectangle (2.7,2);
        \fill [silver] (3.7,1.3) rectangle (5.1,2);
        % Labels
        \draw [thick] (2,1.65) circle (0.2) node [right=0.2] {\Large $I$};
        \fill (2,1.65) circle (0.1);
        \draw [thick] (-0.4,1.65) circle (0.2);
        \draw[thick] (-0.4-0.2*0.707,1.65-0.2*0.707) -- (-0.4+0.2*0.707,1.65+0.2*0.707);
        \draw[thick] (-0.4-0.2*0.707,1.65+0.2*0.707) -- (-0.4+0.2*0.707,1.65-0.2*0.707);
        \draw [thick] (4.4,1.65) circle (0.2);
        \draw[thick] (4.4-0.2*0.707,1.65-0.2*0.707) -- (4.4+0.2*0.707,1.65+0.2*0.707);
        \draw[thick] (4.4-0.2*0.707,1.65+0.2*0.707) -- (4.4+0.2*0.707,1.65-0.2*0.707);
        \node [ao(english)] at (0.6,2.5) {\Large $\bm{H}_\mathrm{O}$};
        \node [anchor=south east] at (6,0) {GGG Substrate};
        \draw [>=Triangle, <->] (6.1,1) -- (6.1,1.3) node [midway, right] {$d$};
        \draw [>=Triangle, <->] (5.5,1.3) -- (5.5,2) node [midway, right] {$2b$};
        % Field
        % Middle
        \draw[thick, ao(english),
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrow{triangle 45}}},
            postaction={decorate}
        ] (2,1.65) ellipse (1 and 0.55);
        \draw[thick, ao(english),
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.28 with {\arrow{triangle 45}}},
            postaction={decorate}
        ] (2,1.65) ellipse (1.15 and 0.7);
        \draw[thick, ao(english),
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{triangle 45}}},
            postaction={decorate}
        ] (2,1.65) ellipse (1.3 and 0.85);
        % Left
        \draw[thick, ao(english),
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrowreversed{triangle 45}}},
            postaction={decorate}
        ] (-0.4,1.65) ellipse (1 and 0.55);
        % Right
        \draw[thick, ao(english),
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.26 with {\arrowreversed{triangle 45}}},
            postaction={decorate}
        ] (4.4,1.65) ellipse (1 and 0.55);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{} \label{fig:SideViewCPW}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{(\ref{sub@fig:TopViewCPW}) Top view of a shorted CPW. Note that for the MSL, the width was given as $2a$, while here, the width of the signal line $W_\mathrm{trans}$ must be distinguishable from the width of the ground plane $W_g$. (\ref{sub@fig:SideViewCPW}) Cross section of a CPW.}
    \label{fig:CPW}
\end{figure}

I've tried to emulate how it is in my project, that's why all the folders are seperated. There is a folder in the project called "tikzpics". Also, I have added a file called "latexmkrc" with just one line in it: <$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape --extra-mem-bot=10000000';>. I was thinking this could have been the solution, but it did not help. This MWE version gives this error:
I can't write on file `tikzpics/output-figure0.md5'.
However, the main project, if I try use externalize (otherwise main memory error) gives this error:
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikzpics/output-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{output}\input{output}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikzpics/output-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikzpics/output-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
I have tried my best to make an MWE, but I am not very experienced. I am unsure how it is best to share my project. Here is a copy of the work so far:
https://sharelatex.tum.de/read/ttbrqyvzsnqg
I am unsure if others are able to see this, without the uni login.
I have also tried using different templates but could not get the \externalize to work on those either. At some point the other templates, alos get a main memory issue. Any help on how I can overcome this, the main memory issue or, preferably, how to get externalize to work, is very appreciated. Let  me know if more information should be provided. This is causing my a lot of trouble before my due date :(
EDIT: Something to add: I have gotten this project to run on VS code using the Latex extension with MikTex and Pearl. However I could not get the \externalze to work. It doesn't seem so trivial, so maybe if someone has experence with this, getting the \externalize to work for on VS could also be a solution

Are you able to download and read the file tikzpics/output-figure0.log?  Are you able to find the first error mentioned in that file?  For trimming down your MWE, look through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497.  It's easiest if you make a new copy of your project, so that you can ruthlessly cut everything not related to your problem.  And have you found https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_tikz%2C_matlab2tikz_or_pgfplots_figures%2C_so_I%27m_getting_a_compilation_timeout._Can_I_externalise_my_figures%3F

note that the recommendation is to switch to a third-party package because these are likely more reliable than the unmaintained external library. this is not currently an option on overleaf, I don't think. certainly one of the two packages I'm aware of was not in the original release of TL 2024 and won't make it to overleaf until the 2025 edition.

After sleeping on it, I noticed that the call \tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzpics/] was not in the preamble. This is stupid, as I lost a lot of time. For those having similar externalize issues: make sure the \externalize call is in the main .tex file and in of course in the preamble (before \begin{document}).
Thanks for the support so far.
